# Radio buttons must return to default state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have radio buttons that are hidden and display based on user input. If the input requires more info, the info MUST be provided.

Should the user change their mind and decide not to answer the questions, they can still process the request.  However, if they previously selected a radio button, it remains checked and will submit false values that have other required and dependent values.

Therefore, if the user changes their mind and decides not to answer, I need the previously checked radios to return null values.  I know it's probably an easy fix for some of you, I would be grateful for any help or direction.  Thank you.`

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $primarySub = $("#primarySub").hide(); // cache and hide in the same call
 $primary = $("#primary").hide(); // cache and hide in the same call
 $secondary = $("#secondary").hide(); // cache and hide in the same call

 $("input[name=visibility]").change(function() {
 $("#visibilityTrue").is(':checked') ? $primarySub.show(): $primarySub.hide(); $primary.hide(); $secondary.hide();

 $("input[name=visibility]").change(function() {
 $("#visibilityFalse").is(':checked') ? $primarySub.hide(): $primarySub.show(); $primary.hide(); $secondary.hide();

 $("input[name=parentChild]").change(function() {
 $("#primaryTrue").is(':checked') ? $primary.show(): $primary.hide();

 $("input[name=parentChild]").change(function() {
 $("#primaryFalse").is(':checked') ? $secondary.show(): $secondary.hide();
            });
          });  
        });
      });
    });


  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <p><strong>Visibility</strong></p>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
          <input name="visibility" type="radio" id="visibilityTrue" value="1">
      visibilityTrue</label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
          <input name="visibility" type="radio" id="visibilityFalse" value="0">
      visibilityFalse</label>
  </div>

  <div id="primarySub" class="animate">
      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
          <p><strong>Primary Item or Sub Item?</strong></p>
          <label class="btn btn-default">
              <input name="parentChild" type="radio" id="primaryTrue" value="1">
          primaryTrue</label>
          <label class="btn btn-default">
          <input name="parentChild" type="radio" id="primaryFalse" value="0">
          primaryFalse</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="primary" class="animate">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="primary">Choose The Order For Primary Item</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="primary" id="primary">
      <option value="1">Primary First</option>
      <option value="2">Primary Second</option>
      <option value="3">Primary Third</option>
      <option value="4">Primary Fourth</option>                        
    </select>                    
    <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block">Please Select One</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="secondary" class="animate">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="secondary">Please Select One</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="secondary" id="secondary">
      <option value="1">Sub First</option>
      <option value="2">Sub Second</option>
      <option value="3">Sub Third</option>
      <option value="4">Sub Fourth</option>                        
    </select>                    
    <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block">Please Select One</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: View the Fiddle here [link] https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=5Gocl1vuzl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Reddy for solving the issue by simply removing a label I had wrapped the buttons in.  Great work buddy!

**Visibility**

```
               <input name="visibility" type="radio" id="visibilityTrue" autocomplete="off" value="1">
                        Yes, Make This Visible

               <input name="visibility" type="radio" id="visibilityFalse" autocomplete="off" value="0">
                        No, Hide This Page
            </div>

            <div id="primarySub" class="animate">
                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <p><strong>Primary Item or Sub Item?</strong></p>

                        <input name="parentChild" type="radio" id="primaryTrue" autocomplete="off" value="1">
                        Should This Be A Primary Item?

                        <input name="parentChild" type="radio" id="primaryFalse" autocomplete="off" value="0">
                        Should This Page Be A Sub Item?
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="primary" class="animate">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="primary">Choose The Order For Primary Item</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="primary" id="primary">
                        <option value="1">Primary First</option>
                        <option value="2">Primary Second</option>
                        <option value="3">Primary Third</option>
                        <option value="4">Primary Fourth</option>                        
                    </select>                    
                    <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block">Please Select One</span>
                </div>
                    </div>

            <div id="secondary" class="animate">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="secondary">Choose The Placement For Secondary Menu Item</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="secondary" id="secondary">
                        <option value="1">Sub First</option>
                        <option value="2">Sub Second</option>
                        <option value="3">Sub Third</option>
                        <option value="4">Sub Fourth</option>                        
                    </select>                    
                    <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block">Please Select One</span>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated you Fiddle. [Here check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/geww079v/5/) **<- UPDATED**

And hers's the code.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

   $primarySub = $("#primarySub").hide(); // cache and hide in the same call
   $primary = $("#primary").hide(); // cache and hide in the same call
   $secondary = $("#secondary").hide(); // cache and hide in the same call

   $("#visibilityTrue").change(function() {
   $(this).is(':checked') ? $primarySub.show(): $primarySub.hide(); $primary.hide(); $secondary.hide();
   });

   $("#visibilityFalse").change(function() {
     if($(this).is(':checked')){
       $("#primaryTrue").prop('checked', false);
       $("#primaryFalse").prop('checked', false);
       $primarySub.hide();
     }
     else{
       $primarySub.show();
     }
     $primary.hide(); $secondary.hide();  
   });

   $("#primaryTrue").change(function() {
   $(this).is(':checked') ? $primary.show(): $primary.hide(); 
   }); 

   $("#primaryFalse").change(function() {
   $(this).is(':checked') ? $secondary.show(): $secondary.hide();
            });

});

//if visibilityFalse = true, then primaryTrue and primaryFalse must be unchecked
```

You had lots of function closing issue, and binding events to unnecessary elements. I have cleaned it up for you. Let me know if this helps

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this.  Unfortunately it's still not working the way I need it to. Click visibleTrue, then click primaryTrue, then click go back up and click "hide this page".  This is the problem:  Everything closes, but false data from the hidden elements will be submitted.  You can verify this by simply clicking on visibilityTrue again and see that the other radio button is still checked.  It must return a null value if visibleFalse returns true.

Comment: The Radio buttons are not checked. Its the button that display the active state. I checked the values in browser console for the radio button checked property value and it seems to be set back to false. I have removed your lable which is wrapping up the radio button. Now you can see what exactly is happening and I see its working as you intended.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks Reddy!

Comment: @Danimal you can mark it as answer if it is the right onw